# How to extract strings from String[] for localization?

Tags: android, string

I'm translating and localizing android app that was written by another dev. I've managed to extract all the strings from code to strings.xml file except for ones in the string-array below. How should I extract strings from this specific String[], and how should I call it back in the code?

```
private static String[] DAYS = {"ned", "pon", "tor", "sre", "cet", "pet", "sob"};
```

Everything that works for other strings in the code, crashes the app when implemented in this array!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please mention question properly @senad

Comment: how should I mention question "properly"? @hareesh145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *string-array*:

in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="days_of_the_week">
        <item>ned</item>
        <item>pon</item> 
        <item>tor</item>       
        <item>sre</item>
        <item>cet</item>
        <item>pet</item> 
        <item>sob</item> 
</string-array>
```

in your Java code:

```
String[] DAYS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days_of_the_week);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to display the localization string of the short day of week string, it's not very necessary to provide your own resources. Java has provide the short day string pattern for you. "EE" stands for the day of week's short string format.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
String dayOfWeeks = df.format(new Date());
```

However, if there is not implementation of your localization string in system. Put the localization string in your resources file values-[localization-qualifier]/strings.xml

```
<string-array name="week_of_days">
    <item>ned</item>
    <item>pon</item>
    <item>tor</item>
    <item>sre</item>
    <item>cet</item>
    <item>pet</item>
    <item>sob</item>
</string-array>
```

Then in your java code, to use the string by following code

```
String[] weeksOfdays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.week_of_days);
```